# Where is a good memory checker for Android?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, usb-debugging, debug

Whenever I try to install/debug an app on my device (Android 2.2.2) I get this error:

```
E/appproc(2974): SETTING DB COPING FAILED, MEMORY DEFECTED....
```

Is there a command-line utility available (or one I could compile with NDK) that will test if memory is defective/mark affected area? I reset to factory data, restored from nandroid, still no obvious way around this error. :(